# How do I write a function that reads a .data file and returns an np array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, data-files

I have a data file that can be downloaded from here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data

I want to define a function that reads and loads the data and returns dataset numpy arrays. Dataset should have 14 columns corresponding to the 13 attributes of housing property x and housing price value y.

```
def loadData(filename):
  dataset = None
  file = open(filename, "r")
  data = file.read()
  print(data)
  x = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
  y = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = 13)
  print("x: ", x)
  print("y: ", y)
  dataset = np.concatenate((x,y), axis = 1)

  return dataset
```

My y output seems to be alright. However, my x output is wrong as seen below:

[image]

Part of the output of x should contain the values below, as part of an np array:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

edit: the above question has been answered and resolved. However, I just wanted to ask how would I ensure that the output is in float64.

My output is [image]

but my expected is [image]

I have edited the np.genfromtxt line to have type = np.float64 as shown:

```
  x = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], dtype = np.float64)
  y = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = 13, dtype = np.float64)
```

I have also tried `dataset.astype(float64)` but neither has worked. Would appreciate some help again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have already read the data from file in `data` variable.
Use `data` variable instead of `filename` in `genfromtxt()` as below instead of filename:

```
def loadData(filename):
  dataset = None
  file = open(filename, "r")
  data = file.read()
  print(data)
  x = np.genfromtxt(data, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
  y = np.genfromtxt(data, usecols = 13)
  print("x: ", x)
  print("y: ", y)
  dataset = np.concatenate((x,y), axis = 1)

  return dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost correct. The problem there is that after loading x you got an array `x` of shape `(506, 13)` (two-dimensional) and an array `y` with shape `(506,)` (one-dimensional). So, after loading `y` you have to add a new dimension to convert it to two-dimensional. `Numpy` offers the `np.newaxis` method for that. The code that solves your problem is:

```py
import numpy as np

def loadData(filename):
  x = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
  y = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols = 13)
  y = y[:, np.newaxis].astype(np.float64) # Add new axis and convert to float64
  dataset = np.concatenate((x,y), axis = 1)

  return dataset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataset = loadData("housing.data")


    """
    print(type(dataset[0, 0]))
    >>> <class 'numpy.float64'>
    """
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, this worked like a charm! However, I realised that I would need to set my output as float64 but I am currently unable to do so as for some reason, the methods I used don't seem to work. I have edited the question to show what I mean as well as the methods used. If you would be so kind as to help me once more, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Hello again! I have updated my answer!

Comment: Hi, I tried it. But it didn't work :(

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure. My output still remained as what is shown in the pic. Basically nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you checked if the `type(...)` of one element inside your array is not `np.float64`. Maybe, it is just a printing issue. You can use my code and run the block     `print(type(dataset[0, 0]))`